# Some of my custom cms pages chaging there url key automatically

Tags: magento-1.9, php, url, cms, url-rewrite

I have number of cms pages but three of which (about-us, contact-us, gallary) changing there url key automatically after some time to (about-us.html, contact-us.html, gallary.html).

I dont know why this happening.

I change that url key many times from admin panel but I think its not permanent solution.

Can anyone tell me permanent solution.

Is anyone having same problem.

Please help me.

Comment: You are sure it is happening automatically, and not in response to some specific action you might be performing in your shop? Some extension might be interfering with the URL keys.

Comment: Then how can I solve this @Prateek .

Comment: And how do I get to know that which extension is making changes. @Prateek

Comment: That one is tricky. Check if there are any extensions installed that perform some SEO related task. To be certain, I'd suggest try disabling them one by one and see if that resolves the issue. But in your case, you should first figure out which action is triggering those URLs to change. It might be CMS page save, product save, or just a cron job trigger.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove .html from all Magento’s category URL then Follow the below steps

1. Go to System -> Config -> Catalog -> Search Engine Optimizations tab
2. Delete “.html” from Category URL Suffix.
3. Go to System->Index Management
4. Reindex “Catalog URL Rewrites”
5. Refresh cache

If you want to remove  .html from all Magento’s product URL then steps will same. Except

2. Delete “.html” from Product URL Suffix.

Comment: My page is working for about-us not for about-us.html What should I do?

Comment: delete all these page and create again with same url  or if you know "URL Rewrite Management" then check requested path and target path of these pages

Comment: I tried that but still it is changing, what to do?